# How many degrees of freedom to diagonalize the metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, linear-algebra, degrees-of-freedom

In A. Zee's *Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell*, he starts with the following expansion of the metric at some point $P$ of a Riemannian manifold, with coordinates $x^\mu$ that have the origin at $P$:

$$
g_{\mu\nu}(x) = g_{\mu\nu}(0) + A_{\mu\nu,\lambda}x^\lambda + B_{\mu\nu,\lambda\sigma}x^\lambda x^\sigma + ...
$$

Then he goes on as:

[image]

If I understand it correctly, we first take a matrix $O$ so that $O^TgO$ is diagonal, which can be done with a orthogonal matrix $O$. Then, we multiply with the matrix $M_{\mu\nu}:=\delta_{\mu\nu}(\sqrt{(O^TgO)_{\mu\mu}})$ to get $K=OM$ and

$$
(K^TgK)_{\mu\nu} = (M^TO^TgOM)_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\mu\nu}
$$

so we have rotated and scaled the coordinates such that the metric is Euclidean in first order.

If that's correct, then so far so good.

Then he goes on to count the number of freedoms we still have in $K$, as well as the number of rotation generators for $D$-dimensional Euclidean space. Both numbers are $\frac 12 D(D-1)$, so:

> We have just shown the fairly obvious fact that in $D$-dimensional space, the freedom we have left in $K$ is precisely the freedom to rotate.

I'm not sure if that's a rigorous proof, but anyway, maybe he's just non-rigorous to make it easier for us students.

**However,**, I can't understand why we still can make rotations without changing the $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ obtained previously. If the original $g_{\mu\nu}$ does not have degenerate eigenspaces, how can we rotate without making it non-diagonal?

Comment: Rotating the coordinates in which the metric is $\delta_{mu\nu}$ does not change the metric (the identity commutes with rotations), does it?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks. Of course the identity commutes with rotations, so the rotation from $K$ and the one from $K^T$ cancel each other out: $O^T\delta_{\mu\nu}O=\delta_{\mu\nu}$. Right?